# How can i download file in Codeingiter

Tags: codeigniter, download

I want to give download  file option my webpage , but the file which i want to download is present on download link of another website , how can i directly download it from my webpage ,using CODEIGNITER

Comment: review my answer if you have any Question let me know.

Comment: The download helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html#force_download

Comment: hy man if you think my answer is use full for you please accept it so that will help others. @shubhangi

Answer (score 1):

If you want download a file direct to your web site root folder use this code.

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/your_folder_name/add_file_name.jpg..ect", "your_file_path_want_to_download");
```

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download files using download helper in codeigniter. first you need to and $this->load->helper('download'); in your constructor or method. after that use following code for download.

```
force_download('/path/to/photo.jpg', NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use download helper in Codeigniter. simple load helper in your controller where you need like this

```
$this->load->helper('download');
```

here is ex

```
$data = 'Here is some text!';
$name = 'mytext.txt';
force_download($name, $data);
```